# Conditioning series with positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have  to prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is a convergent series with positive real numbers, then  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_{n})^\frac{n}{n+1}$ converges. I also wonder if the converse is true. Any suggestion, hint will
be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: for the converse note that at the end of the series you have the following inequality $ a_n \leq a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if $a_n \geq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \Rightarrow a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}} =\frac{a_n}{a_n^{\frac{1}{n+1}}} \leq 2a_n$ if $a_n \leq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ then $a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1} } \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$. Therefore $a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1} } \leq 2a_n + \frac{1}{2^n}$ and by comparison test you are done.